# Flurry Analytics iOS archive error

Tags: ios, xcode, flurry

I successfully integrated the Flurry Analytics. But after I wanted to archive and upload to iTunes Connect, there was an error shown below:

> ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7 slice: /Users/Frank/Desktop/Desktop/IOS/FalconTech/FalconTech/Flurry/libFlurryWatch_8.4.0.a file '/Users/Frank/Desktop/Desktop/IOS/FalconTech/FalconTech/Flurry/libFlurryWatch_8.4.0.a' for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

and there is the image of showing file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot, you are not building an app that includes Watch. You can fix the error by removing the Watch Library.